# Use SDWebImage to load a image for imageview, How can i get the width of image?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdwebimage

when i use setImageWithURL to load online image, i got 0.000000,
  but when i load local image,i got the correct width.

```
NSURL * url1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.hb.aicdn.com/7f46b5eb65320f18f797a4a26ebe9ba328b547832f7b3-KYR0Xn_fw192"];
UIImageView * img2=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 192,400)];
[img2 setImageWithURL:url1];
//[img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.gif"]];
//load local image

[self.view addSubview:img2];
CGFloat height1=img2.image.size.width;
NSLog(@"%f",height1);
```

Comment: u dont display any code using SDWebImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a very old question but I got the same problem a while ago and thought my answer could help someone who runs into the same problem.

To get the image width, you should download the image independently with SDWebImageManager. I'm pretty sure it is explained in their wiki page.

Here is the example code to do the task :

```
-(UIImage *)downloadImageAsync:(NSString *)imageKey
{
    NSLog(@"image key : %@",imageKey);
    __block UIImage *returnedImage;
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageKey] options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize){
        NSLog(@"received size %d expected size %lld", receivedSize, expectedSize);

    }completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType,BOOL finished){
        if(image && finished) {
            returnedImage = image;
        }
    }];

    if(returnedImage == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Returned Image Nil");
    }
    return returnedImage;
}
```

So when the UIImage finishes downloading, you can get the width and height of it. Hope this helps.

Cheers.